# How could i remove the prefilled input on clicking into a InputField in PySimpleGui?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

i am new to python, so sorry for some simple questions...

I have a layout in PySimpleGui like this:

`layout = [ ...., [sg.InputText("yourInput", key='-INPUT-')], [sg.Button('Ok')] ]`

This creates an Input TextBox with Prefilled > yourInput in it.
How could i empty the TextBox, when the User clicking in the Textbox?
At the moment i have to mark the Word yourInput and/or overwrite it.

Is there any other more professional way?  :-)

It is of course working, but at the moment it gives the user not a professional look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

Here I did it by the tkinter code to validate the input.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class Input(sg.Input):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.default_text = "Enter Your Password"
        self.default_color = 'grey'
        self.revised = False
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def initial(self):
        self.update(self.default_text, text_color=self.default_color, move_cursor_to=0)
        vcmd = (self.widget.register(self.validate), '%S', '%P', '%d')
        self.widget.configure(validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)

    def validate(self, char, text, insert):
        self.widget.config(validate="none")
        if self.revised:
            if not text:
                self.revised = False
                self.update(self.default_text, text_color=self.default_color, move_cursor_to=0)
                result = False
            elif not text.isalnum():
                result = False
            else:
                result = True
        else:
            if insert != '1':
                result = False
            elif not char.isalnum():
                result = False
            else:
                self.revised = True
                self.update(char, text_color=sg.theme_input_text_color())
                result = False
        self.widget.configure(validate="key")
        return result

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
layout = [[Input(key='-IN-')]]
window = sg.Window('Demo', layout, finalize=True)
window['-IN-'].initial()
window.read(close=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you bind to focus-in as a simpler way?

Comment: Focus-in does not do a good job about this issue because it shouldn't clear the hint when focus in, but when firstly key in.